# C++ Macro Arguments w/ Token Concatenation?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a bunch of labeled servos, each one has its own calibrated min, mid and max pulse-width value.

```
// repository of calibrated servo pulse width values:

#define SERVO_0x01_MIN 165
#define SERVO_0x01_MID 347
#define SERVO_0x01_MAX 550

#define SERVO_0x02_MIN 165
#define SERVO_0x02_MID 347
#define SERVO_0x02_MAX 550
...
```

To simplify maintenance of the code, swapping a servo should only require changing a single macro definition value.

```
// maps certain positions on robot to the servo that is installed there
#define JOINT_0 0x02
#define JOINT_1 0x05
#define JOINT_2 0x0A
...

// function-like macros to resolve values from mapping
#define GET_MIN(servo) SERVO_##servo##_MIN
#define GET_MID(servo) SERVO_##servo##_MID
#define GET_MAX(servo) SERVO_##servo##_MAX
```

The problem I'm having is that calling a function-like macro with an argument that itself is a macro does not resolve to its terminal value:

```
// main
int main(void) {

    // this works
    int max_0x01 = GET_MAX(0x01);  // int max_0x01 = 550;

    // this doesn't
    int max_joint_0 = GET_MAX(JOINT_0);  // int max_joint_0 = SERVO_JOINT_0_MAX;
}
```

What can I do to make `GET_MAX(JOINT_0)` turn into `550` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define GET_MAX(servo) GET_MAX2(servo)
#define GET_MAX2(servo) SERVO_##servo##_MAX
```

The preprocessor will perform expansion (textual replacement) upon a variadic macro until it can expand no further. So passing in `JOINT_0`, such as `GET_MAX(JOINT_0)` will expand to

```
GET_MAX2(0x02)
```

This gets further expanded to

```
SERVO_0x02_MAX
```

And finally replaced with the `#define` value 550

Comment: Wow! Thanks - could you please add a brief explanation why this works?